# Facebook Social Plugin not Showing

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I am trying to get the Activity Feed Social Plugin to display on this website: http://wrdtempsite.com.au/qualdes/
(It's WordPress run and has the WordPress SEO plugin installed which has FB meta data)

Nothing shows at all, but I get no errors. (It should display on the right hand side of the homepage).

Code below:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXX";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-activity" data-site="http://wrdtempsite.com.au/qualdes/" data-app-id="XXXXX" data-width="300" data-height="600" data-header="true" data-recommendations="false"></div>
```

I cannot see what is wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a fix? I see the "recent activity" block, but it says "No recent activity to display."

Comment: I have just completed working on it.... would you believe it was a css rule that pushed the widget off the side of the screen! A Facebook default css rule too. Still not, sure why nothing is being pulled in though?!

Comment: That FB plugin pulls in pages or articles that have been "Liked" via a Facebook "Like" button on your site. I don't see any Like buttons (please don't make me write Like again!) on your pages, so that site won't have had any actions that could show up in the activity block. You can get the code for the button at this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Thanks Nate for the help! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It was a css rule that was basically 'hiding' the widget from view.

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe {position:absolute;}
```

I changed that to position relative.